# Angular 1.5 routing example

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am trying to locate an angular 1.5 routing example using $route. The JSFiddle examples I've looked at break if I use higher angular version than used to create the code example. I can't find anything working above 1.2. Ideally I need a working example for AngularJS 1.5.

I have already tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/NEuJ6/) example:

```
var app = angular.module( "myApp", [] );

app.config( function ( $routeProvider ) {
  $routeProvider
  .when( '/this', { templateUrl: 'this.html' } )
  .when( '/that', { templateUrl: 'that.html' } )
  .when( '/other', { templateUrl: 'other.html' } )
  .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/this' } );
});

app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function ( $scope ) {
});
```

Which fails for 1.2 (and presumably above).

Comment: i tried this one of my own. again works for angular 1.0 and fails for 1.2. http://jsfiddle.net/pa6gyu7x/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When AngularJS 1.2 was released `ngRoute` has been moved into its own module. This means you need to include a seperate file to get routing to work above and equal AngularJS 1.2. This means the first thing to do is to include `angular-route.js` file, just as you would include any other script

```
<script src="angular-route.js">
```

Second, have include the dependency to your app module.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'otherModule']);
```

Last, you can configure your `$routeProvider` as you did in your code above:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/',{
          template: '<h1>Work</h1><a href="#/test">Test Route</a>'
      })
      .when('/test',{
          template: '<h1>Test</h1><a href="#/">Back</a>'
      })
      .otherwise({ 
        template: '<h1>Not Found</h1>'
      });
});
```

That's the whole setup magic behind the routing. Here is a working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TFhEKYPVOtlmFOwYEMGi?p=preview).

**Edit 1:**

If you are using `bower` you can get the module with the following:

```
bower install angular-route
```